# Run java weka utility

Tags: java, weka

I wonder how it is possible to use specific weka utility.

For exaple, I want to use the following utility [TextDirectoryToArff](http://weka.wikispaces.com/file/view/TextDirectoryToArff.java/82917281/TextDirectoryToArff.java).

I tried to run it as follows

```
javac TextDirectoryToArff.java

TextDirectoryToArff.java:21: package weka.core does not exist
```

and like following

```
java -jar /usr/share/java/weka-3.6.6.jar TextDirectoryToArff.java
```

and in this case weka starts and not the utility.

How it's possible to run the utility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first have to compile the `TextDirectoryToArff.java` file. This is done with `javac`. The error message in your case just indicates that you did not tell him where to find the weka classes that are required for the compilation. You can tell him where he can find these classes by specifying the classpath (cp) :

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/weka-3.6.6.jar TextDirectoryToArff.java
```

This should create a file `TextDirectoryToArff.class` in the current directory.

In order to start this utility, you can simply call

```
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/weka-3.6.6.jar TextDirectoryToArff
```

Note that you do *not* use the `-jar` parameter, because you do not want to run what is inside the JAR, but the TextDirectoryToArff class directly. Therefore, you again have to specify the classpath. In this case, the classpath contains current directory (indicated by the `.`) (because it contains the `TextDirectoryToArff.class` file), and, separated from that with a `:`, the path to the weka JAR.

You'll also have to specify a directory name, so the full command line will be something like

```
java -cp .:/usr/share/java/weka-3.6.6.jar TextDirectoryToArff your/directory/name
```

Comment: I have one more question, do you know how to run `java weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader -dir text_example > text_example.arff`?

Comment: Again, you have to specify the classpath: `java -cp /usr/share/java/weka-3.6.6.jar weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader -dir text_example > text_example.arff`